# Getting an error when generating an SDM with the R SDM package's ensemble function

Tags: r

I'm attempting to build a climatic species distirbution model using 3 separate techniques: glm, maxlike, and gam. I'm using the sdm package in R. After generating the model, I'm trying to use the `ensemble()` function to generate a weighted average of those three models based on the AUC statistic and then output that to a map I can plot.

sdmShp is a SpatialPointsDataFrame of presence-only points generated from GBIF data. CDTClimate is a clipped raster object of climate data imported from Worldclim.

```r
library(sdm)

modelData <- sdmData(formula = PA ~ AnnMeanTemp+AnnPrecip, train = sdmShp, predictors = CDTClimate, bg=250)

model <- sdm(PA ~ AnnMeanTemp+AnnPrecip, data = modelData, methods=c("glm","maxlike", "gam"), replication = c('sub', 'boot'), test.percent = 30, n=5, modelSettings = list(ncore= "1L"))

map1 <- ensemble(model, newdata = CDTClimate, filename = "map1data.img", setting=list(method='weighted', stat='AUC'), 
overwrite=TRUE)
```

The model runs fine, but when I attempt to use the ensemble function I get the following error:

```
Error in if (ncore < w$ncore) w$ncore <- ncore : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I've tried adding a modelSettings parameter to the ensemble function similar to what I did for the sdm() function, but it didn't change anything. There doesn't appear to be any information in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sdm/sdm.pdf) about using ncore in the ensemble function. What do I need to do to get this to work?